# Groovy script fails to add edges to a Gremlin graph

Tags: groovy, graph, closures, gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm trying to make this script work to retrieve all edges that are present in a file, with ratings from users to movies.

```
new File('ratings.dat').eachLine{
    line ->

    components = line.split('::');

    userId = components[0].toInteger();
    movieId = components[1].toInteger();

    g.V().has('userId', userId).as('o').V().has('movieId', movieId).addE('rated').to('o');
}
```

If I add some debug-prints inside this closure I can see that all the information is being loaded correctly to my variables, but at the end of the execution I count the number of edges in my graph and it is increased by only 1, when it should be multiple. A bit of investigation showed that the edge being effectively added to the graph is the last to be read. What could have possibly gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never execute your traversal. Your code should look like this:

```
new File('ratings.dat').eachLine { def line ->
    def (userId, movieId) = line.split('::')*.toInteger()
    g.V().has('userId', userId).as('o').
      V().has('movieId', movieId).
      addE('rated').to('o').iterate()
}
```